# Boton de compartir en facebook con meta-tags

Tags: html, botón, facebook

quiero establecer parametros para compartir con el boton de facebook y su documentacion no me funciona, eh intentado con muchos codigos y nada me funciona, solo me sale una imagen que no estableci y no se mas que puedo hacer, aca esta mi codigo

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>PRUEBA TITULO</title>
    <!-- You can use Open Graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
  <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.manuelcaldas.com/muestras.php" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
   <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.manuelcaldas.com/imagenes/PV213_medium.png" />

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <!-- Your share button code -->
  <div class="fb-share-button" 
    data-href="http://www.manuelcaldas.com/muestras.php" 
    data-layout="button_count">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Quise ver si me salia en la descripcion esa "Your Description" y me sale otra cosa

Answer (score 1):

¿Puedes colocar ese código en tu sitio web de producción para depurarlo?, actualmente tienes otro código que es inválido.

Usa https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ para extraer la información Open Graph de nuevo, pues es un robot que no lo hace en "tiempo real".

Saludos

Comment: Y por si acaso no sabes si la url de la imagen debe ser solo de la pagina? no puede ser una url de imagen de otra pagina?

Comment: Mientras sea accesible si. Aquí tienes documentación oficial http://ogp.me/